# spring batch: How To call my RollBack implementation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I Have my own Spring Batch Job (**MyTaskletJob**) that implements my interface **IJobBase**  that implements **Tasklet**,

What I need that my job to implement another method called **rollBack**

public interface **IJobBase** extends **Tasklet**{

```
 void rollBack();
```

}

public class **MyTaskletJob** IJobBase{

```
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1){

            …}
    public void rollBack(){

            …}
```

}

The Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="jobTaskletStep1" class="com....job.MyTaskletJob ">
    <property name="message" value="Hello..." />
</bean>
<batch:job id="backgroundJob">
<batch:step id="step0">
        <batch:tasklet ref="jobTaskletStep1"/>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

This is the way I run my Job:

// create the job according to job name

**Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean(“backgroundJob”);**

// run the job – the **jobLauncher** will run the **MyTaskletJob** **execute** method

**JobExecution myJobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);**

// check the ExitStatus

**If(myJobExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED)){**

// Need to run **rollback()** method on  **MyTaskletJob**

**My question is how to invoke the method rollback() method when JobExecution FAILED**

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use a JobExecutionListener#afterJob(JobExecution).  You can inject the reference to your jobTaskletStep1 into the listener.  From there you can check the status set in the JobExecution and call the method as needed.

Comment: how could i inject the reference to the Job jobTaskletStep1